# Prove: $x^a$ and $x^b$ are integers implies $x$ is an integer for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ iff $a$ and $b$ are coprime?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

For given positive integers $a$ and $b$, consider the proposition:

> $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}(x^a\in\mathbb{Z}\land x^b\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow x\in\mathbb{Z})$

My question is: for what positive integers $a$ and $b$ is this proposition true?

For example, it is true for $a=2,b=3$:

Assume for contradiction that $x\in\mathbb{R},x\notin \mathbb{Z},x^2\in\mathbb{Z},$ and $x^3\in\mathbb{Z}$

Then $x$ is irrational and $x^2>0$. Then $x^3=x^2x$ is the product of a nonzero integer and an irrational number, so $x^3$ is irrational. But we assumed $x^3$ is an integer, so we have a contradition. Hence, the proposition holds.

For another example, consider $a=b=2$. In this case, the proposition clearly doesn't hold for $x=\sqrt 2$.

I'm hypothesizing that the proposition holds exactly when $a$ and $b$ are coprime. I don't know too much number theory, so I'm not entirely sure how to prove this. If it's false, I can't think of a counterexample. Can anyone prove or disprove my hypothesis?

Comment: Well, your *original* question you answered yourself: No!  (I was going to use that same counterexample of $a=b=2$) .. maybe you should change the title to reflect that what you are really asking is the question at the end of your post?

Comment: @Bram28 Sorry if the title is misleading, but I had to abbreviate it somehow

Comment: I just went ahead and did add this to the the tile ... I think it fits.  I hope that's ok with you?

Comment: @Bram28 It's better but still not exactly what my question is, because I'm also hypothesizing that if $a$ and $b$ are not coprime, then the proposition doesn't hold. The new title is only the forward implication of what I'm trying to prove, but I think that's fine.

Comment: How about now? It's even a little shorter :)

Comment: @Bram28 hmm maybe I'll just add that the LHS must be true for all x in R. I'll edit it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(a,b)=1$, then write $ar+bs=1$ for $r, s\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$x=x^{ar+bs} = (x^a)^r(x^b)^s\in\mathbb{Q}.$$
Note that either $r$ or $s$ could be negative, so we can only conclude that $x$ is rational from the above. However (see comment below), since $x$ is rational, and some power of it (for example, $x^a$) is an integer, $x$ itself must be an integer.

If $(a,b)=d>1$, take (for example) $x = \sqrt[d]{2}$.

Comment: Using $ar+bs=1$ seems the way to go, but since $r,s$ can be negative it's not clear that the product is an *integer*.

Comment: Per quid's remark, in the first case you show that x is *rational*. However, some positive power of it is an integer, so it has to be an integer itself.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks. I was about to delete the answer, but you saved it.

Comment: Nice, this is a very elegant proof!